# Using Redis with multiple nodes in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis

We have created 2 nodes for Redis in AWS, where first will be the primary which will be used for write and second one will be used for read operations.

My question is how can I make the connection to those endpoint while writing/reading to and from redis in .NET application using connection string.

As of now we are doing like below which we need to change for Read/Write endpoints
startup.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRedis, RedisCaching>();

builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
    {
        options.Configuration = builder.Configuration.GetSection("{rediscacheendpoint}");
    });
```

I want to read multiple connection strings and use it whichever is needed using `IDistributedCache` DI, while reading/writing data from redis